# How Authorize.net Automated Recurring Billing counts months?

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net, recurring-billing

I make application which use `Authorize.net Automated Recurring Billing` and I found some ambiguity:

When we add `subscription` which make transactions in interval of one month how it works?

**Example 1**

It started on 15 July, then make transaction on 15 August, 15 September and so on... Ok.

**Example 2**

It started on 31 January... so?

It month leasts 30 days? I need to know how it exactly works. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you submit a subscription with a start date of the 31st, then the next subscription payment will run on the last day of each month. When you set the interval to month, the ARB service tries to run each payment on that same day each month. But for your example, since that date doesn't always exist each month, it would instead run on the last day of the month.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to know Is your knowlege is from some documentation, or you have tried it on yourself? Becouse I have searched it and do not find any results. If you can attach some link or sth I will be grateful.

Comment: I got the answer from their community forums. Their community manager posted that exact answer which I copied and pasted here.